# Kivy 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'

Tags: python, kivy

I am receiving the following error in my Kivy application but I am not sure why and how to fix it:

```
File "main.py", line 16, in __init__
self.seq_text_box = self.parent.ids.seq_text_box
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'ids'
```

Basically, all I'm trying to do is access the text box within the methods of the `MenuBar` class. I'm new to this so it's likely I'm misunderstanding something.

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class SequenceTextBox(TextInput):

    pass
    #...


class MenuBar(BoxLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.seq_text_box = self.parent.ids.seq_text_box

    def go(self):

        print(self.seq_text_box.text)


class MinuRoot(BoxLayout):
    pass


class MinuApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MinuApp().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
MinuRoot:

<MinuRoot>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MenuBar
    SequenceTextBox
        id: seq_text_box

<MenuBar>:
    height: "40dp"
    size_hint_y: None
    Button:
        text: "Go!"
        on_press: root.go()

<SequenceTextBox>:
    focus: True
```

I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store `seq_text_box` as an [`ObjectProperty`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#kivy.properties.ObjectProperty) of `MenuBar` and set it in the `kv` file:

```
class MenuBar(BoxLayout):
    seq_text_box = ObjectProperty()
    def go(self):
        print(self.seq_text_box.text)
```

and in the `kv` file:

```
<MinuRoot>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    MenuBar:
        seq_text_box: seq_text_box
    SequenceTextBox:
        id: seq_text_box
```

The reason you receive the error is because in the constructor the `ids` haven't been populated from the rules specified in the `kv` file.

If you do want to use a plain attribute, you can schedule a `Clock` event:

```
class MenuBar(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MenuBar, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.init_seq_text_box, 0)

    def init_seq_text_box(self, *args):
        self.seq_text_box = self.parent.ids.seq_text_box
```

This will schedule a call to `init_eq_text_box` for the next frame, when `ids` will be populated.